# In the context of vectors, is there a difference between the terms "magnitude" and "length"?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, terminology

I noticed vectors are usually said to have "length" and "direction", but then it is said that people want to find the "magnitude". Is this just a difference in terminology or is there something more to it?

For example, [here](http://www.ditutor.com/vec/vector_magnitude.html) they discuss "magnitude" and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) they use the word "length".

Answer (score 21):

This is just a difference in terminology. This quantity is also called the *norm* of a vector. If we are thinking of a vector as representing the line segment from the origin to a given point, we may interpret the norm as the *length* of this line segment. If we are thinking of a vector as representing a physical quantity like acceleration or velocity, we may interpret the norm as the *magnitude* of this quantity (how "large" it is, regardless of its direction).